# Подставить в метод document JS значение переменной? Собрать метод JS с переменных?

Tags: javascript

```js
change_property = function(this_el) {
  var a = "width";

  document.getElementById(name_seting_box.innerHTML).style.a = this_el.value + "px";

};
```

Если прописать

```js
document.getElementById(name_seting_box.innerHTML).style.width = this_el.value + "px";
```

работает. Как правильно записать первый вариант. Помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует альтернативный синтаксис работы со свойствами, использующий квадратные скобки `объект['свойство']`

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['phrase'] = 'Привет'; // то же что и myObj.phrase = 'Привет'
```

Следовательно, нужно писать в таком же стиле:

```
change_property = function(this_el) {
  var a = "width";

  document.getElementById(name_seting_box.innerHTML).style[a] = this_el.value + "px";

};
```

Comment: Голос поставить не могу, так как новичок. Спасибо. Все работает!!!))))

Comment: А есть возможность  собрать метод с переменных    var a = "width";
var b = "getElementById";
  document.b(name_seting_box.innerHTML).style[a] = this_el.value + "px";